# Python:How can i make an instance of an class with a dictionary?

Tags: class, object, python-3.x, dictionary

bare in mind please that i'm a beginner in programing.
I made the following piece of code and it doesn't work. I assume it has to do with the creation of the **room1** instance of **Locations**.
Here's the code:

```
class Location:    
def __init__ (self, name, description, location, **actions):
    self.name = name
    self.description = description
    self.location = location
    self.actions = actions

def test (self):
    self.actions = actions
    print (actions)
    x = type(actions)
    print (x)

room1 = Location("Bedroom","First Room",1,S="Search", M="Move")
room1.test()
```

Comment: "it doesn't work" **How** does it not work?

Comment: it says :  NameError: name 'actions' is not defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the dictionary as such:

```
Location("Bedroom", "First Room", 1, {"S":"Search", "M":"Move"})
```

EDIT:

Okay, so I see where things are going wrong for you.

You want to change your test method to look like:

```
def test (self):
    print (self.actions)
    x = type(self.actions)
    print (x)
```

You don't need to reassign self.actions in the method, it's already been initialized.

Comment: it says invalid syntax

Comment: TypeError: __init__() takes 4 positional arguments but 5 were given

Comment: Change how you're calling the class when you create `room1` to conform with the new signature of `__init__`.

Comment: same problem, guess it's not caused by class name "Location"

Comment: No problem, remember to mark the question as answered.